# Run SUM(*) on Supabase

Tags: supabase-database

I'm starting with Supabase and would like to understand how I can pass the `SUM()` aggregator in a `SELECT`.

I noticed that for `COUNT` we use:

```
const { data, error, range, count } = supabase
  .from('table')
  .select('*', { count: 'exact' })
```

Is there anything similar to `SUM` that I haven't noticed?

My query is this:

```
select
  "GE_PRODUCTS",
  sum("GE_QUANTITY") as Quantity,
  sum("GE_SALEVALUE") as Revenue
from "GE_SELLS"
where "GE_ENTERPRISE" = 'G.E.'
  and "DELETED" <> '*'
group by "GE_PRODUCTS"
order by Revenue desc
limit 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to put this into a [PostgreSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createfunction.html) and [call it from Supabase](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/rpc) using `.rpc()`:

Comment: Can you provide an example PostgreSQL function using OP's query?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_my_sums() 
    RETURNS TABLE (
        "GE_PRODUCTS" TEXT,
        Quantity NUMBER,
        Revenue NUMBER
) AS $$
DECLARE 
    var_r record;
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select
    "GE_PRODUCTS",
    sum("GE_QUANTITY") as Quantity,
    sum("GE_SALEVALUE") as Revenue
    from "GE_SELLS"
    where "GE_ENTERPRISE" = 'G.E.'
    and "DELETED" <> '*'
    group by "GE_PRODUCTS"
    order by Revenue desc
    limit 3;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).